# Special characters in mathematica

Tags: symbols

I'm currently making a plot and want to demarcate a couple of points. I would like to label them $\widetilde\alpha$ and $\hat\alpha$. How can I do this?

Comment: Type `α`, then press Ctrl + 7, then type `~` or `^`.

Comment: Look up `OverHat[]` and `OverTilde[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) in `Graphics`.  [This page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SelectingAndTypingInNotebooks.html), and the ones linked under Tutorial (top right corner) explain how to type math.

Here's one way, keystroke by keystroke:

<kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd> or <kbd>^</kbd>

Copyable example:

```
Graphics[Text["\!\(\*FormBox[OverscriptBox[\(a\), \(^\)], TraditionalForm]\)", {0, 0}]]
```

It'll format fine when you paste back to Mathematica.

---

You can also use my package [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html), if you like that style of formatting.

Comment: Just a minor issue, I believe OP wants `\[Alpha]` instead of `a`.

Comment: I'm not going to retype that, but OP:  α is typed as ESC a ESC.